# How to return Value from Multi Threading?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface, native

My problem is, i just want to return value from Multi threading out of 4 threads running concurrently in Multiple times. I need a return value for every times thread calls and run. Please justify me thank you, My code snippet looking like this, Thread1: i was calling java to native library function, function returns integer value.

```
 public void run() {
            double time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            println("Thread-1 starts " + time);
            ED emot = new ED();
            emot.edetect("str");
            try {
              Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch {

            }
            println("Value: " + emot.getvalue);
            i = emot.getvalue;
                }
```

Comment: so you want to return the i at the end? where do you want to use that value?

Comment: Use a Future and ExecutorService

Comment: @SinePike yes i want to use that ' i 'value for another class but thread running multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multi threaded environment, we can return the values from thread by using Executer Service. This feature is available from JDK 5.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

Example :

```
public class MyThread implements Callable{

    @Override
    public String call(){
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return "Hello";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
          ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
          Callable<String> callable = new MyThread();
          String value = executor.submit(callable);
          System.out.println("The returned value is : "+value);
          executor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

This is the way you can return the values from thread.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I got your problem you have 4 threads which return some value after computation. Here are few ideas:

1. If your thread returns some result use `Callable<V>` else `Runnable`.
2. You can use `ExecutorService` to submit your task (thread) and will get `Future<V>` or `Future<?>` depending on whether it is `Callable` or `Runnable`.
3. If you want to receive result of all the threads you can submit all and get futures and then invoke `future.get` which blocks until result is received. If you want to receive result from any of the threads then in that case you can also use [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) as well which maintains a queue of results in whatever order they are received.

Answer (score -1):

You could make that object, emot, a class variable.  This way, when you make the new object in your main thread, you could access that value through a getter method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Your code

    YourRunnableClass r = new YourRunnableClass();
    Thread yourThread = r;
    yourThread.start();

    //other code

    r.getValue() //The value you are trying to get
}

public class YourRunnableClass implements Runnable {

    private ED emot;

    public int getValue() {
        return emot.getvalue();
    }

    public void run() {
        //Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Iam not able to assign                                                               YourRunnableClass r = new YourRunnableClass();
    Thread yourThread = r; Type mismatch cannot convert from YourRunnableClass to Thread